# Left Join two tables & group by a column into an array

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

Let's assume we have two tables:
`websites`

| **id** | **label** |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | my.website.com |
| 2 | new.app.gov.uk |

And `domains`:

| **id** | **websiteId** | **domain** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | domain1.info |
| 2 | 1 | domain2.io |

Can I left join them so I can get something like:

| **id** | **label** | **domains** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | my.website.com | [domain1.info, domain2.io] |
| 2 | new.app.gov.uk | [] |

Comment: Yes, you can. Haven't you tried it? In order to convert the outer join result (three rows) to one row per id, aggregate your data. I suggest you try this and come back in case you get stuck.

Comment: I tried but did not work, any hints?

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Comment: I wrote my code for msSql and modified it,I also put the mysql code. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The STRING_AGG() is an aggregate function that concatenates rows of strings into a single string, separated by a specified separator. It does not add the separator at the end of the result string.

Use this snippet for MySql:

```
SELECT t1.id,t1.label,IFNULL(CONCAT('[',GROUP_CONCAT(domain),']'),'[]')  as domains
 FROM websites t1 
 left join domains t2 
 on t1.id=t2.websiteId 
 group by t1.id,t1.label
```

Output:

```
id  label           domains
1   my.website.com  [domain1.info,domain2.io]
2   new.app.gov.uk  []
```

Use this snippet for SQL-Server :

```
SELECT t1.id,t1.label,isnull('['+STRING_AGG(domain,',')+']','[]')
  FROM websites t1
  left join 
  domains t2
  on t1.id=t2.websiteId
  group by t1.id,t1.label
```

Output:

```
id  label           domains
1   my.website.com  [domain1.info,domain2.io]
2   new.app.gov.uk  []
```